# 64 Bit Ubuntu onyl recognizeds 3.5 GB of 6 GB RAM

Tags: ram

I had 4 GB of RAM only 3.5 was usable, I enabled pae when I installed antoehr 2 GB and it yet only came up with 3.5 GB and now I've wiped my hard drive and installed 64 Bit Ubuntu and its yet only recognizing 3.4 GB of my ram actually  I run a dedicated graphics and have tried cleaning  and swapping the slots my ram was in

```
  PCI (sysfs)  
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A11
       date: 11/30/2006
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 448KiB
       capabilities: pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppytoshiba int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb ls120boot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 700
       size: 16KiB
       capacity: 16KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back data
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 701
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1000
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 6GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: 6400EL Series
          vendor: 7F7F7F7F7F020000
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_1
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: KC6844-ELG37
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: B01EBFEE
          slot: DIMM_3
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: 6400EL Series
          vendor: 7F7F7F7F7F020000
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_2
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: KC6844-ELG37
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: B01EC9EE
          slot: DIMM_4
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
```

Comment: please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/667537/edit) your question, and add the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run unequal quantities or different speeds or different voltages or basically any 2 RAMS that are not the same model and size without running into a problem.

this is because the computer can only assign equal sizes of RAM for a task so if a task requires 3GB of RAM (theoretically) then there would be a fatal error.

So there is no hardware support for this. Same problem with different speeds

Different manufacturers also cause a problem because of incompatibility. So you cannot have 6GB of RAM especially if they run at different clock speeds. you can have 2GB, 4GB, 8GB and so on, with equal sizes of RAM

EDIT: saw your quantities later but same theory applies, you cannot divide "channels" into unequal quantities causing fatal errors (hence no hardware support). BTW get RAM with higher frequency for a performance upgrade, a lot of the power lies in the clock speed and 500mhz is extremely low when there are 3000mhz sticks available now!

Check overclockers.com and tomshardware.com (many more) for more info about this.

Basically problem isn't in ubuntu so this is the wrong forum to ask this question. Even at those forums you'll get an answer like "it won't work for you (most probably) but if it does then don't run it cause it'll cause more damage than it'll do good"

Comment: `You cannot run unequal quantities or different speeds or basically any 2 RAMS that are not the same model and size without running into a problem.` - Not quite true.  I run different sizes all the time, as well as different manufacturers and have never had a problem.

Comment: @Daniel It is not good for your system and if you check my edit you will see the answer i most commonly receive to my similar questions.    [quote]"it won't work for you (most probably) but if it does then don't run it cause it'll cause more damage than it'll do good"[/quote]     Please do some basic hardware research.

Comment: check some of these links for more info:
http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2618645/6gb-ram.html


http://www.howtogeek.com/199070/would-using-unequal-amounts-of-ram-in-each-slot-decrease-performance/

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1959585/pairs-ram-manufacturers.html

Comment: And what do you mean by `the computer can only assign equal sizes of RAM`?

Comment: A computer assigns equal amounts of memory to a task if you have 2 sticks of RAM. So if you have a task which requires 500MB of ram then 250MB would be given to each stick

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27585/discussion-between-pranay-and-daniel).

Comment: But that only applies to dual-channel architecture.

Comment: well my ram is dual channel 2x2gb and 2x1 gb but then knowing that i can only use 3.5 gb of ram is it better to run 32 or 64 bit maybe be doing some server hosting set this computer up for starmade server but may aslo wanna do soem gaming cause i do have a dedicated draphics

Comment: 64 bit either way, cause you can still upgrade to 8GB or more plus you get more functionality. 32 bit is meant for less than 2GB memory.